# how to show message welcome to 'user log in' in php?

Tags: php, session

i have got Undefined Index : nmguru.

this is the code and i want to show welcome with *name user logged in*

```
 <?php 
if($_SESSION['typelog']="guru"){
   echo "-==Welcome ".$_SESSION['nmguru']."==-"; }
   else if($_SESSION['typelog']="admin"){
   echo "-== Welcome Admin ==-"; }
   else {
   echo "<b>Selamat Datang di Website Sistem Informasi Akademik</b>";
   } 
   ?>
```

Comment: You're assigning, not comparing. To compare two values, you need to use double equality `if ($_SESSION['typelog'] == "guru") {`

Comment: still not working and now unidentified variables after adding ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the $_SESSION['typelog'] value to "guru"  by using only one equals,  replace it with this:

```
if($_SESSION['typelog']=="guru"){
```

The same applies here, you need to replace the single = :

```
else if($_SESSION['typelog']=="admin"){
```

So the complete code should be:

```
if($_SESSION['typelog'] == "guru"){
   echo "-==Welcome ".$_SESSION['nmguru']."==-"; 
}elseif($_SESSION['typelog'] == "admin"){
   echo "-== Welcome Admin ==-"; 
}else {
   echo "<b>Selamat Datang di Website Sistem Informasi Akademik</b>";
}
```